# With VLOOKUP, if N/A, keep original value

Tags: microsoft-excel, vlookup

I'm using Vlookup to find a value, but when it doesn't work, it returns N/A.  How do I keep the previous value instead of having NA.  I have found the answer [HERE](http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/56519-if-vlookup-=-n-keep-original-cell-value.html)

How do I implement this? Do I just copy paste that into the excel sheet? or in the vb module?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer there is using VBA, so you would need a VBA function.
But you can do the same without VBA, using iferror:

```
=iferror(vlookup(cell,range,1,0),cell)
```

It will output the `vlookup` result if it succeeds, `cell` otherwise.